# How can I query random number of values for a unique id and concatenate them into one?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery, bq

I have a table with 2 columns, 1st is client name let's say, and second is his choices.
Note he can chose multiple choices (1 or more)! and may do a 2nd order as well!

Input is as follows for example:

```
| Client   | Order item       |
| -------- | ---------------- |
| User 1   | 1-cola           |
| User 1   | 2-fries          |
| User 1   | 3-burger         |
| User 2   | 1-cola           |
| User 2   | 2-fries          |
| User 3   | 2-fries          |
| User 3   | 1-cola           |
| User 4   | 3-burger         |
| User 5   | 1-cola           |
| User 5   | 2-fries          |
| User 5   | 3-burger         |
| User 5   | 3-burger         |
| User 5   | 1-cola           |
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is to get a single row for each order as follows:

| Client | Order item |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 | 1-cola - 2-fries - 3-burger |
| User 2 | 1-cola - 2-fries |
| User 3 | 1-cola - 2-fries |
| User 4 | 3-burger |
| User 5 | 1-cola - 2-fries - 3-burger |
| User 5 | 1-cola - 3-burger |

Note!
1- In order for client 3 the items are ordered when concatenated!
2- In order for client 5 we have 2 orders, detected simply by having a duplicate item for that order so it was put in a new row!

I know it's a bit complicated, but I am really wondering if possible to do that!
Hope I described it well!

BR,
Naz

Comment: sql rows are unorded with respect to other rows. There's no difference between the two `1-cola` for `User 5`. Make an `orderId` column in your table.

Comment: What is your primary key?

Comment: @raymondnijland in that case, look again

Comment: How do you identify the "second order"?

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select client, 
  string_agg(order_item, ' - ' order by order_item) as order_items
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by client, order_item) as client_order
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
group by client, client_order
# order by client, client_order
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Note: logic you described in the question is a little fuzzy - so identifying new order(s) and "spreading" items across multiple orders of the same client can be different from what it was in reality. To "fix" this  - you need to add more "players" into your logic - maybe timestamp and/or explicit row indicating new order

Comment: Thanks heaps Mikhail, really appreciated help, I'll test further and get back!
..
Yes, actually it is more complicated than this but I tried to simplify and get an idea on how to achieve this part, but not sure is it better to ask the full question in a new one or here? (btw. data is coming from GA, so yes we have timestamps for each hit).